# Interstitial Ads In Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, admob, interstitial

I made an iOS app with xcode, I am using webview, I have already implement google admob banner ads but now i also want to show Interstitial ads in my app without click any button, I mean when my url loads Interstitial ads shoud show. I am using this code, but not works

```
interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "")
    let request = GADRequest()
    // Request test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
    // an ad request is made.
    request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID, "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ]
    interstitial.load(request)

    if interstitial.isReady {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
```

and in AppDelegate.m

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

But ads doesn't show, I can't see any error in xcode log, please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not skip to import your AppDelegate to "GoogleMobileAds" and connect the GADInterstitialDelegate. And try this in the AppDelegate if your ID's are true:

```
   var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
   var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "yourApplicationID")
    return true
}

func showInterstitial(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "youradUnitID")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.delegate = self
    // Request test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
    // an ad request is made.
    //request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID, "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ]
    interstitial.load(request)
}

func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {

    if(self.interstitial.isReady){
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: (self.window?.rootViewController)!)

    }
}

func interstitialDidFail(toPresentScreen ad: GADInterstitial) {
    NSLog("")
}
```

If there is a error you can show the failure in the console